# PB mongodb, mongoose, node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I get this error when I try to insert something in mongodb, can you give me a doc for understand and do what I need please ?

```
        /home/samp/Bureau/Node/gw/gw-user/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:413
            throw err;
                  ^
    MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: 
mongoose-bcrypt-test.users.$username_1  dup key: { : "samp@hotmail.com" }
```

this is my code:

```
  user.save(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duplicate key error means you are trying to insert a value (from what it looks like samp@hotmail.com) that already exists in MongoDB as a unique key. Use another user value.

Comment: ty very much. I find a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

If the value you are trying to add is already present then you will get this error. I used _id field for simplicity.

```
> db.test.insert({_id:123,Name:"test1"})
> 
> db.test.insert({_id:123,Name:"test2"})
E11000 duplicate key error index: test.test.$_id_  dup key: { : 123.0 }
>
```

Comment: ty for your answer, but when this happen my server shut down.